# how to use will paginate helpers in my own helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, will-paginate

Hi i created my own helper and passed the array of objects to it. And from there i want to get the pagination results.

```
def processed_pagination
    content_tag(:div, will_paginate(@object), :class=>"list-pagination")
end
```

but it is generating error

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'get?' for nil:NilClass):`

I also tried to include in the class

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

but no way, error is still there.

Can any one guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing @object to your helper method?

```
def processed_pagination(@object)
    content_tag(:div, will_paginate(@object), :class=>"list-pagination")
end
```

In your view you can do:

```
processed_pagination(@object)
```

Comment: I changed the code `def processed_pagination(object)
        content_tag(:div, will_paginate(object), :class=>"list-pagination")
      end` and called it by `processed_pagination(@object)`. Now the error changed to `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Atlantis::DataList::Helper):`

Comment: Hmm, I was just looking at will_paginate's api and it looks like they have built in support for customizing class names and such. See: http://rubydoc.info/gems/will_paginate/2.3.15/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers:will_paginate . Also I'm not sure about your new error. I would probably try and see if everything works without the helper first (ie just try a basic will_paginate in the view).

Comment: If i declare the method in the application helper, it works fine. But if declare that method in my own custom helper. It would not. Whats the problem in it?